# How to find adjacent pairs in a sequence, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For one of my assignments, I have to write a code that will look for adjacent pairs in a sequence. If there are no pairs in the sequence, the output has to be None. Could be a list, string, whatever. The code that I have only worked for half of the test files (the true ones), yet I am having trouble passing the false test files. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and would like help to complete this task. Here is the code I am working with:

```
def neighboring_twins(xs):
    twins = False
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(xs)):
            if xs[i] == xs[j]:
            twins = True
     return twins
```

sample inputs:

```
xs = [1,1]
```

output = `true`

```
xs = [2,1,2]
```

output = `False`

```
xs = []
```

output= `False`

Comment: Please fix your indentation. I tried to edit but I don't know which line belongs where

Comment: Please also provide sample input and desired output

Comment: There is no need for two `for` loops. In fact that's one reason for the wrong result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through `xs` starting from the *second* item, and compare to the previous item:

```
def neighboring_twins(xs):
    for i in range(1, len(xs)):
        if xs[i] == xs[i-1]:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you. I see what I was doing wrong and your code makes much more sense than what I was doing.